# how to mount a disk partition in docker

Tags: linux, docker

I have the below sd card partition from `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sdb1: PARTLABEL="uboot" PARTUUID="5e6c4af7-015f-46df-9426-d27fb38f1d87"
...
...
...
/dev/sdb8: UUID="5f38be2e-3d5d-4c42-8d66-8aa6edc3eede" BLOCK_SIZE="1024" TYPE="ext2" PARTLABEL="userdata" PARTUUID="dceeb110-7c3e-4973-b6ba-c60f8734c988"
/dev/sdb9: UUID="51e83a43-830f-48de-bcea-309a784ea35c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="rootfs" PARTUUID="c58164a5-704a-4017-aeea-739a0941472f"
```

I am trying to mount `/dev/sdb9` into a docker container so that I can reformat it and do other stuffs with it.

But I am not able to attach it as a volume in docker container.

This is what I've done:

```
docker volume create --driver=local --opt type=ext4 --opt device=/dev/disk/by-uuid/51e83a43-830f-48de-bcea-309a784ea35c my-vol
docker run <image id> -v my-vol:/my-vol -it bash
```

However, it came up with the error: `failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.`

Any ideas how i can mount `/dev/sdb9` into a docker container?

Comment: You will run into some other trouble, even if you fix the syntactic trouble with the option order that @ChrisDoyle describes.  A Docker container intentionally does not have access to hardware devices, especially raw disks, as part of Docker's general isolation model, and since a container only runs one program, the underlying image usually won't have the tools you need to manage these disks.  This task might be better run directly on the host system, and as a non-programming task, it might be better discussed somewhere like [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your docker run command so that the options come before the image. Everything after the image is considered as args, you need to provide options such as volume before the image name. From the docker run docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/:

`docker container run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

```bash
$ docker run -it ubuntu -v $(pwd):/local
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

```bash
$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/local ubuntu
root@8fa69b8861d8:/#
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for this. it seems to work with `$(pwd)` to mount the current directory. but any idea how to mount `/dev/sdb9` into the docker container? still getting errors: `failed to mount local volume: mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/51e83a43-830f-48de-bcea-309a784ea35c:/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-vol/_data: no such file or directory.`

Comment: You but what if you use the method you were doing before `docker run -v my-vol:/my-vol -it  <image id> bash` where you had alaredy created the volume with a device option. You cant attach a device as a volume directly. you would have to use something like `docker run -it --device /dev/disk/by-uuid/e17a595e-18f3-45e3-8f22-e0d1005fbae1 ubuntu` but then you would have to map it to a volume etc. Try running the `-v` flag before the image but using the volume you created